# What's the meaning of "to render/give plausibility to the myth"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of: "to render plausibility to the myth"

The mere possibility that we can choose and replace our rulers appears sufﬁcient to render plausibility to the myth that we are ruling ourselves

Answer (score 1):

It gives as a reason to believe that the myth might, after all, be true.

Answer (score 0):

I have rephrased the complete sentence for better understanding:

"Just the possibility of choosing and replacing our rulers is enough to validate the myth that we are ruling ourselves"

“to render/give plausibility to the myth” means that the myth is provided validation of being apparently true.